# Photo slideshow that plays a list of images from top to bottom seamlessly

Tags: windows, open-source, image-viewer, slideshow

I have long page captures that needs to be viewed from top to bottom in 1:1 size. I want to scroll through these images using (mouse wheel or up/down key) or play them automatically just like a webpage. Is there any software (preferably desktop) that can do just this?

I made a web prototype [here](https://picscrollview.pages.dev/) demonstrating what I need. I feel like this should be a small feature of some popular software right? Though I can't seem to find it and I don't know the right word.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I hacked together a web prototype: https://picscrollview.pages.dev/

Comment: That's a bot from reviews. Pinging it has no purpose. Please edit the question with additional info instead.